# looking for the name of a particular concept in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming

In ruby, you often execute methods like `has_many` or `validates` when you instanciate a class. Is there a name to designate this kind of method  specifically created to be called at class instanciation ?

Comment: At the language level those are just _class methods_. You can invoke them without a receiver because `self` refers to the class instance when you're inside the class body. At a conceptual level you could say it's a _domain specific language_ for configuring your models.

Comment: As an aside this should read: "In Ruby on Rails..." as neither one of those methods are part of ruby core or standard libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [Stefan's excellent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70438303/looking-for-the-name-of-a-particular-concept-in-ruby#comment124513962_70438303)...

They are *[inherited](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/01/what-is-inheritance-in-ruby/) [class methods](https://medium.com/rubyinside/class-methods-in-ruby-a-thorough-review-and-why-i-define-them-using-class-self-af677ede9596)* forming a [*domain specific language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) used to [*make declarations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) about the class.

---

Those are all [*class methods*](https://medium.com/rubyinside/class-methods-in-ruby-a-thorough-review-and-why-i-define-them-using-class-self-af677ede9596), so called because you call then directly on the class. `self` will be the class. As opposed to instance methods which are called on the instance of the class, the object.

They are also *inherited* methods from `ActiveRecord`, they are
not defined within your class but in an ancestor class or module.

---

More specifically, they form a *domain specific language*; a DSL. These are method calls written in a specific way to seem like a new language. For example,

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  validates :terms_of_service, presence: true, acceptance: { message: 'must be abided' }
end
```

Is really...

```
Player.validates(
  :terms_of_service,
  presence: true,
  acceptance: { message: 'must be abided' }
)
```

Which is a wrapper around...

```
Player.validates_presence_of(:terms_of_service)
Player.validates_acceptance_of(:terms_of_service, message: 'must be abided')
```

Which is a wrapper around...

```
Player.validates_with(PresenceValidator, :terms_of_service)
Player.validates_with(AcceptanceValidator, :terms_of_service, message: 'must be abided')
```

Which is a wrapper around pushing validation objects onto a Hash of validations for this class.

```
# Roughly...
Player._validators[:terms_of_service] << 
  PresenceValidator.new(
    attributes: [:terms_of_service]
  )
Player._validators[:terms_of_service] << 
  AcceptanceValidator.new(
    attributes: [:terms_of_service],
    message: 'must be abided'
  )
```

---

Finally, Domain Specific Languages are form of [declarative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming#Domain-specific_languages).

In other types of programming you tell the program how to do it. For example, let's say you wanted to make sure an attribute is a positive integer greater than zero. You can do it procedurally...

```
object.number.match?(/^\d+$/) && object.number > 0
```

Or you ask a specific method to do it...

```
NumericalityValidator.new(
  attribute: [:number],
  only_integer: true, greater_than: 0
).validate(object)
```

But in declarative programming you declare how it's going to be and the language figures out how to make it happen.

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  validates :number, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
end
```

You probably already know two declarative languages: SQL and Regular Expressions.